# Cannot resolve module 'fs' in .../node_modules/geoip-lite/lib

Tags: node.js, react-redux, fs, geoip

I'm using a project with `react-redux-starter-kit` module, I installed `geoip-lite` module, and when I imported it, the errors said in the title appeared.

```
ERROR in ./~/geoip-lite/lib/geoip.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in <path>/node_modules/geoip-lite/lib
 @ ./~/geoip-lite/lib/geoip.js 1:9-22

ERROR in ./~/geoip-lite/lib/fsWatcher.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in <path>/node_modules/geoip-lite/lib
 @ ./~/geoip-lite/lib/fsWatcher.js 1:9-22
```

In `webpack.config.js` file, I've already tried to modify the `target` to `node` instead of `web`, which is the default, but then the warning below appeared and the website running locally got all blank.

```
WARNING in ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js
Critical dependencies:
9:12-34 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/encoding/lib/iconv-loader.js 9:12-34
```

I've also added `node: { fs: 'empty' }` in the file, but then, this error in the screen:

```
TypeError: fs.openSync is not a function
```

I tried to install `fs` within the module and also download `fs-extra` and change all occurrences of `fs` to `fs-extra`, but no success at all. What can be done?

Comment: Are you using webpack in order to run bundled code in a browser?  Because there is no full featured `fs` module that can run in the browser.

Comment: I am. I did see about this already, but doing the suggestions lead me to more issues.

Comment: You simply can't use the `fs` module or any other module that depends upon it in a browser.  The browser does not have a substitute for that functionality.  Neither webPack or browserify can magically give the browser file access powers (or any other native code capabilities) it does not have built in.

Comment: Why is there such module then? Is there any alternative?

Comment: The `fs` module exists for running code with node.js and is a built-in part of node.js.  If you're trying to run code in a different environment like the browser, then only a subset of the modules are applicable.  So, when finding modules in NPM (you apparently found the geoip-lite module, then you have to find modules that are compatible with the browser environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add target: 'node' in webpack config section, like this :

```
var webpackConfig = Object.assign(
  {
    target: 'node',
    ....
};
```